# aws scp Host key verification failed

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using centos7 .If tried the below way  with pem file included scp works  but when pem file is removed its not working.  Code was working earlier without pem file . After We moved to a different web server   we are having Host key verification failed issues.

```
 scp -i/home/centos/sshkeys/test.pem root@77.79.77.72:/usr/local//2016/Aug/31/ggea98c0-6f0f-11e6-86d9-2573a2e556aa.wav /var/www/html/tmp/ggea98c0-6f0f-11e6-86d9-2573a2e556aa.wav
```

Comment: change that root user to centos and then check?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your key was registered in ~/.ssh/config or it was your default key in ~/.ssh ? Check on the old server ?

Edited:

For example this is what I put in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host myserver
Hostname 52.100.100.100
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/dev/application/server-key.pem
```

It allow me to connect simply by `ssh myserver`. Maybe it was something like this that you had on your server.

Comment: Thanks  a lot.  Are you talking about authorized_keys file?  Where do I need to put aws pem file